# How to join two strings and add a name python in CSV

Tags: python

Csv data is below

```
X,Y
3.4,45
34,5.5
5,55
```

Code is below

```
with open(r'C:\Users\ma\Desktop\m.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    row['Z'] = ",".join( row['X'],row['Y'])    
    print (row)
```

GOt error >> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Expected out will be like this Z is combination of X and Y

```
X,Y,Z
3.4,45,"3.4,45"
34,5.5,"34,5.5"
5,55,"5,55"
```

Comment: It looks like you're reading into `reader`, but you're accessing `row` when doing the `join()`.

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf, i want to put the data back, also i have other variables also like id,address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```py
import csv

with open(r'C:\Users\ma\Desktop\m.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    coordinates = []
    for row in reader:
        x = row[0]
        y = row[1]
        coordinates.append({"x": x, "y": y, "z": f"{x},{y}"})
```

`coordinates` will be:

```py
[{'x': '3.4', 'y': '45', 'z': '3.4,45'},
 {'x': '34', 'y': '5.5', 'z': '34,5.5'},
 {'x': '5', 'y': '55', 'z': '5,55'}]
```

Once you have `coordinates`, you can use the following code to get that specific output:

```py
print("X,Y,Z")
for e in coordinates:
    print(f'{e["x"]},{e["y"]},"{e["z"]}"')
```

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to do with pandas

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("m.csv", dtype=str)
df["Z"] = '"' + df["X"] + "," + df["Y"] + '"'
```

Output:

```
   X    Y         Z
0  3.4   45  "3.4,45"
1   34  5.5  "34,5.5"
2    5   55    "5,55"
```

Answer (score 1):

try this, `csv.DictReader` + `list comprehension`

```
import csv

with open(r'read_path') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    lines = [{**r, **{"z": ",".join(r.values())}} for r in reader]

with open('write_path', 'w') as fw:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(fw, lines[0].keys())
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(lines)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want it in simple python, check the below code. However, I would suggest using "pandas" when working with large datasets.

```
import csv

with open('sample.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        combined_column = ",".join(row)
        if combined_column == "X,Y":
            combined_column = "Z"
        else:
            combined_column = '"{combined}"'.format(combined=combined_column)
        # print(combined_column)
        row.append(combined_column)
        row_string = ",".join(row)
        print(row_string)
```